# Embed multiple matplotlib figures in wxPython

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I have a 2x2 `FlexGridSizer` in a panel and I want to insert four different matplotlib figures with their own toolbars at the same time.

I have seen many links related and working examples embedding one figure, but as I am a begginer with wxPython and OOP I get quite confuse when testing some codes and trying to merge them with mine.

Here is a piece of the page class of a `wx.Notebook` where I want to put the figures

```
class Pagina(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.boton_descargar = wx.Button(self, -1, label=u"Descargar")
        self.boton_desconectar = wx.Button(self, -1, label=u"Desconectar")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        subsizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        subsizer2 = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=2, cols=2)

        sizer.Add(subsizer1, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 0)
        sizer.Add(subsizer2, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 0)
        sizer.Add(self.boton_desconectar, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.RIGHT, 10)
        subsizer1.Add(self.boton_descargar, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClick_descargar, self.boton_descargar)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClick_desconectar, self.boton_desconectar)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def onClick_descargar(self, event):
        HiloDescarga()

    def onClick_desconectar(self, event):
        pass
```

`HiloDescarga` is actually a thread launched to download some text lines, process data and plotting this way (the fourth figure is the same thing):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

line, = plt.plot(range(len(x)), x, '-', linewidth=1)
line, = plt.plot(range(len(x)), f, 'y-', linewidth=1)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title(r'title1')
plt.grid()
plt.figure()

line, = plt.plot(range(len(y)), y, 'r-', linewidth=1)
line, = plt.plot(range(len(y)), g, 'y-', linewidth=1)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title(r'title2')
plt.grid()
plt.figure()

line, = plt.plot(range(len(z)), z, 'g-', linewidth=1)
line, = plt.plot(range(len(z)), h, 'y-', linewidth=1)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title(r'title3')
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

so the figures are just popping in separated windows. If you could give me a snippet or at least some orientation, perhaps a few changes to the plotting code, I don't know. Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to follow the examples where they embed one Figure, but instead instantiate several members for each of the figures you want to create.
Here is a quick example:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
import wx


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, nbFigures=4):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.figs = [Figure(figsize=(2,1)) for _ in range(nbFigures)]
        self.axes = [fig.add_subplot(111) for fig in self.figs]
        self.canvases = [FigureCanvas(self, -1, fig) for fig in self.figs]
        for canvas in self.canvases:
            sizer.Add(canvas, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

app = wx.App()
frm = MyFrame(None)
frm.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

I've saved the instances of each figure in the array `self.figs` and each instances of the axes on each figure in `self.axes`

Hope that puts you in the right tracks

Comment: I'm gonna give this a try in a minute. I have one doubt though. Is it a good idea to start a new thread for the plotting task? My standalone plotting script takes a while to do it.

Comment: Sorry, can't really help you with that